# Script don't order list (Python)

Tags: python

I have two lists which need to be ordered. The first one work...

```
list = ['1.png', '2.png', '4.png', '5.png', '3.png', '6.png']
a = sorted(list)
print(a)
```

It sort the list by ascending order. In this second list, it sort it by the first lower digit..

```
list2 = ['10.png', '12.png', '8.png', '4.png', '22.png', '41.png']
a = sorted(list2)
print(a)
```

It print out this: `['10.png', '12.png', '22.png', '4.png', '41.png', '8.png']`

How can I properly order it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list contain a list of str not integer

```
list2 = ['10.png', '12.png', '8.png', '4.png', '22.png', '41.png']
list2.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0]))
```

Output:

```
['4.png', '8.png', '10.png', '12.png', '22.png', '41.png']
```

Comment: work perfect. it's the answer.. lambda is live, lambda is life ;)